# Для нестатического поля метода или свойства требуется ссылка на объект

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static string Model;

        public const
            string Sm = "Samsung";
            string Lg_ = "LG";
            string Sn = "Sony";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Вы пришли в магазин за телевизором");
            Console.WriteLine("К вам подошёл консультант и предлогает вам помочь");
            Console.WriteLine("Какую модель вы хотите? Samsung, LG, Sony?");

            Model = Console.ReadLine();
            if (Model == "Samsung")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Вы выбрали телевизор" + Sm);
            }
            else if (Model == "LG")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Вы выбрали телевизор" + Lg_);
            }
            else if (Model == "Sony")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Вы выбрали телевизор" + Sn);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Такой модели в нашем списке нет!");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Класс телевизора Samsung
    /// </summary>
    public class Samsung
    {
        public static int Price, Weight, Diagonal;
        public static string Color, Matrix;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Класс телевизора LG
    /// </summary>
    public class LG
    {
        public static int Price, Weight, Diagonal;
        public static string Color, Matrix;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Класс телевизора Sony
    /// </summary>
    public class Sony
    {
        public static int Price, Weight, Diagonal;
        public static string Color, Matrix;
    }
}
```

Кто может помочь, что нужно сделать?

Comment: Учите язык и правила разработки, поймите ПОЧЕМУ и ЧТО значат ошибки, они же не просто так вам выдаются. За вас это, к сожалению, никто не сделает. Общие вопросы навроде "у меня ошибка, что делать?" не несут SO обществу никакой полезной информации. Объясните что вам известно, что нет, и что именно вам не понятно - тогда, глядишь, люди и подтянутся.

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае модификатор

```
public const
```

Относится *только* к полю `string Sm = "Samsung";`. Следующие поля

```
string Lg_ = "LG";
string Sn = "Sony";
```

Являются обычными полями класса, не константами и не статическими.

Для решения нужно либо использовать данный модификатор для всех трех полей

```
public const string Sm = "Samsung";
public const string Lg_ = "LG";
public const string Sn = "Sony";
```

Либо использовать запятую вместо точки с запятой:

```
public const
    string Sm = "Samsung",
    string Lg_ = "LG",
    string Sn = "Sony";
```